# AttrFieldSliderGrp command used in MEL/Python in Maya

Tags: python, user-interface, slider, maya, mel

I wanna move the edge of 3D object with a slider in Maya UI.

Is it possible to move any component (vertex, edge or face) but not the whole object with the `attrFieldSliderGrp` command using `-at` flag?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `AttrFieldSliderGrp` command you can translate a vertex:

```
window -title "Sliders for moving a vertex";
    polySphere;
    string $sphere[] = `select -r pSphere1.vtx[199]`;
    columnLayout;
    attrFieldSliderGrp -min -5.0 -max 5.0 -at ($sphere[0]+".pntx");
    attrFieldSliderGrp -min -5.0 -max 5.0 -at ($sphere[0]+".pnty");
    attrFieldSliderGrp -min -5.0 -max 5.0 -at ($sphere[0]+".pntz");
showWindow;
```

[image]

But you can't translate edges and faces with `AttrFieldSliderGrp` command because there are no `tx`, `ty` and `tz` attributes for them.
Nonetheless, there are `polyMoveEdge` and `polyMoveFacet` (`cmds.polyMoveEdge()` and `cmds.polyMoveFacet()`) commands for moving edges and faces via MEL and Python:

```
polySphere -name myEdges;
select myEdges.e[199];
polyMoveEdge -t 2.0 1.0 0.7 myEdges.e[199];

polySphere -name myFaces;
select myFaces.f[200:201];
polyMoveFacet -t 1.8 0.8 1.1 myFaces.f[200:201];
```